# Modifying an ng-repeat "track by" or "as" in an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

If you have a directive that contains an ng-repeat and you want to modify the "track by" or "as" of the ng-repeat how do you do that without creating two separate ng-repeats in the template?  I would like to be able to pass in the track by of the ng-repeat as a directive attribute.  So in the case of the string array it would just be something like repeat-track-by="row" and in the case of the object array it would be repeat-track-by="row.title".  Is there any way to achieve this?

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app")
.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.sampleData = ["sample 1", "sample 2", "sample 3"];
  $scope.sampleData2 = [{title:"sample 1"}, {title:"sample 2"}, {title:"sample 3"}];
})

angular.module("app")
.directive("repeatDirective", function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        template: "<div ng-repeat='row in data track by row'>{{row}}</div>",
        link: function (scope) {}
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <repeat-directive data="sampleData"></repeat-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can use arbitrary expressions in track by, including references to a custom function on $scope, though the purpose of replacing the tracking function isn't clear, since the track by doesn't affect anything except duplicate detection in an array;  it would be much easier to just sanitize the data.

Comment: what complications arise using `$index` for both?

Comment: The service that I am posting to is expecting data in a particular format. So for instance...  Let's say I have data = [{title: "sample", value: 12345}, {title: "sample2", value: 23456}].  In a standard ng-repeat I would use ng-options="row.value as row.title for row in data".  Now I want to put that into my ng-repeat directive, but I want the directive to be flexible enough to not have a static "row.value as row.title".  How would I go about achieving that?

Comment: don't confuse what you are trying to achieve by replacing terminology.  `ng-options` is not the same as `ng-repeat`, so saying "In a standard `ng-repeat` I would use `ng-options="`" doesn't make any sense, and only serves to suggest you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: besides, what are you ***really*** trying to accomplish by re-engineering an already working directive like `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Apologies.  That is correct.  I got thrown off by the ui-select directive using "repeat" in place of "ng-options".  I am not trying to re-engineer ng-repeat.  The actual directive that I have contains a great deal more than just the repeat.  I am just using this as a simple example to address what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am going to try to use an arbitrary expression as originally suggested.

Comment: @Claies - Using an arbitrary expression worked.  Thank you very much for the suggestion.  Sorry about the ambiguity in how I was trying to ask the question.  This is for a select box, but it is a ui-select box...  which is technically just an ng-repeat.  If you post that comments suggestion as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: honestly, if you solved your issue with using an expression, it's probably better for others in the future if you create a self answer, and can demonstrate how your expression solved the problem.

Comment: seems like solution has nothing to do with the question.... comments are very confusing as they diverge from what the question asked

Comment: @charlietfl that was my thoughts as well; the moment that the comments went from `track by` to `ng-options`, it was clear that the OP would be better to provide their own answer showing what it is they were trying to solve, and the expression that solved it;  an answer of "just use an arbitrary expression" wouldn't be helpful, and certainly wouldn't clarify the actual problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  I will write up an answer using the expression that I created and post that.